# 3-tier web application subnet segmentation in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS VPC setup for 3-tier web application. I created a VPC with subnet 10.0.0.0/16, and what is the good best practice to do the subnet segmentation in AWS VPC for 3 tier web application? I have ELB with 2 EC2 instances, and RDS and S3 in the backend.

Please advise!! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The way we do it:

We create a VPC that is a /16, e.g. 172.20.0.0/16. Do not use the default VPC.

Then we create a set of subnets for each application “tier”.

- Public - Anything with a public IP. Load balancers and NAT gateways are pretty much the only thing here.
- Web DMZ - Web servers go here. Anything that is a target for the load balancer.
- Data - Resources responsible for storing and retrieving data. RDS instances, EC2 database servers, ElastiCacahe instances
- Private - For resources that are truly isolated from Internet traffic. Management and reporting. You may not need this in your environment.

Subnets are all /24. One subnet per availability zone.  So there would be like 3 Public subnets, 3 Web DMZ subnets, etc.

Network ACLs control traffic between the subnets. Public subnets can talk to Web DMZ. Web DMZ can talk to Data. Data subnets can talk to each other to facilitate clustering. Private subnets can’t talk to anybody.

I intentionally keep things very coarse in the Network ACL. I do not restrict specific ports/applications. We do that at the Security Group level.

Pro tip: Align the Subnets groups on a /20 boundary to simplify your Network ACLs rules. Instead of listing each data subnet individually, you can just list a single /20 which encompasses all data subnets.

Some people would argue this level of separation is excessive. However I find it useful because it forces people to think about the logical structure of the application. It guards against someone doing something stupid with a Security Group. It’s not bulletproof, but it is a second layer of defense. Also, we sometimes get security audits from customers that expect to see a traditional structure like you would find in an on-prem network.

Answer (score 2):

A common pattern you will find is:

- **VPC with /16** (eg `10.0.0.0/16`, which gives all `10.0.x.x` addresses)
- **Public subnets with /24** (eg `10.0.5.0/24`, which gives all `10.0.5.x` addresses)
- **Private subnets with /23** (eg `10.0.6.0/23`, which gives all `10.0.6.x` and `10.0.7.x`) -- this is larger because most resources typically go into private subnets and it's a pain to have to make it bigger later

Of course, you can change these above sizes to whatever you want within allowed limits.

Rather than creating a **3-tier structure**, consider a **2-tier structure**:

- **1 x Public Subnet per AZ** for the Load Balancer (and possibly a Bastion/Jump Box)
- **1 x Private Subnet per AZ** for *everything else* — application, database, etc.

There is no need to have apps and databases in separate private subnets unless you are super-paranoid. You can use **Security Groups** to configure the additional layer of security without using separate subnets. This means less IP addresses are wasted (eg in a partially-used subnet).

Of course, you could **just use Security Groups** for everything and just use one tier, but using private subnets gives that extra level of assurance that things are configured safely.

Comment: Does 1 subnet mean 1 physical box? For the private subnet of application server and database server, does it mean they are in the same box? I think it is a best practice to have segmentation and place in different box. What will the configuration look like if place in separate box?

Comment: No. A subnet is a logical division of a VPC network. It is totally unrelated to the resources that are virtually "connected" to the network. Just like you can plug a physical computer into a router, each EC2 instance is connected to a subnet purely for network connectivity.